# folders in google app

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new with python, and this question is about access a folder inside of the root.

With this url `http://localhost:8080/` I can access the root folder of the application. But if i create a subfolder inside of `engineapp` how can i access it by url?

In my case i am trying `http://localhost/folder:8080` but apparently this doesn't work. What is the correct way to do that?

And I should copy the `app.yaml` and `index.yaml` from the `engineapp` to the new subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map a [path into a handle](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running)r or a [static handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles).
Handler is for generating content using code while static handler is for static content (like scripts, images, css, etc).